# RightFax Server Setting

Tags: vb.net, rightfax

I am currently doing integration to rightfax which using visual basic. There are some basic settings in order to establish connection.

I would like to ask the server name it is limited to servername only or IP address also acceptable?

Because currently I am using IP but it return me an error "The system cannot find the file specified" Anyone can kindly advise me? Appreciate for any reply.

```
gl_MyFaxServer = New RFCOMAPILib.FaxServer()
        gl_MyFaxServer.ServerName = "172.17.80.167"
        gl_MyFaxServer.Protocol = RFCOMAPILib.CommunicationProtocolType.cpNamedPipes
        gl_MyFaxServer.AuthorizationUserID = "ADMINISTRATOR"
        gl_MyFaxServer.AuthorizationUserPassword = "password01"
        gl_MyFaxServer.UseNTAuthentication = RFCOMAPILib.BoolType.False

        gl_MyFaxServer.OpenServer()
```

Comment: Care to show us those settings and the code? why would an IP address vs a Server name result in a file not found?

Comment: Can you run ProcessMonitor and see which file `The system cannot find the file specified`?

Comment: Unfortunately, the given laptop from company is hard to run the process monitor because it is very lag. Between how do I determine which file the system cannot find the file specified by using the process monitor? Currently I am using Microsoft Visual Studio 2010.

Comment: Run it anyway. Download ProcessMonitor and start it up. It will start tracing Disk, Registry, Processes in real time. Stop the trace and clear it. Get ready to reproduce the problem, start ProcessMonitor Tracing then once the File Not Found has happened stop the trace. Save the trace as a CSV, open it in Excel, Filter, and Filter the column with the Access Denied type of errors.

Comment: C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE\Web\Visual Basic PATH NOT FOUND
C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE\FSharp\General PATH NOT FOUND
C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE\Modeling NAME NOT FOUND
C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE\VisualBasic\Code PATH NOT FOUND
C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE\VisualBasic\General PATH NOT FOUND
C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE\CSharp\Reporting PATH NOT FOUND

Comment: C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\Common7\IDE\PrivateAssemblies\Idle.DLL NAME NOT FOUND

Comment: @JeremyThompson, it is too many records regarding to visual studio, totally cannot determine which one trigger the error, what to do?

Comment: I suspect your running ProcessMonitor on your PC, when its the Server "172.17.80.167" that is having the error. Please delete above 3 comments and run ProcessMonitor on the server while you quickly reproduce the problem. Then post a link to the results or the main ones of interest (if the data is sensitive) in your question and please specify the line the error is occuring on `gl_MyFaxServer.OpenServer()`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error caused because of authentication failure.
Make sure from the provided details by using them to connect to the right fax server via "RightFax FaxUtil".

One more thing, the "Administrator" account set without password for RightFax Server. So try to comment "gl_MyFaxServer.AuthorizationUserPassword = "password01" " line. Don't pass empty string, just remove the password assignment.

Answer (score 1):

Have you installed the FaxUtil client to install the dll files needed?